# With a JSON file how would I list two objects thats are inside an array using JQ?

Tags: arrays, json, linux, parsing, jq

Here is the top of my Json file. I am attempting to list two objects and its contents. I want to list the description and rtmp_url.

```
   {
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "geometry": {
            "coordinates": [
              -55.37174,
              55.77598
            ],
            "type": "Point"
          },
          "properties": {
            "direction": "EB",
            "mrm": 55,
            "id": "555",
            "jurisdiction": "test",
            "route": "I-64",
            "description": "test description",
            "deviceid": "",
            "rtmp_url": "test url1",
          
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "geometry": {
            "coordinates": [
              -55.36782,
              55.77382
            ],
            "type": "Point"
          },
          "properties": {
            "direction": "WB",
            "mrm": 44,
            "id": "4444",
            "jurisdiction": "test 2 jurisdiction",
            "route": "I-64",
            "description": "test 2 description",
            "deviceid": "",
            "rtmp_url": "test rtmp_url",
            
          }
        },
```

I want my output to be this. I just want to Grab  "description": & "rtmp_url":

```
test description test url1
test 2 description test rtmp_url
```

This command

```
jq '.features[] | {description, rtmp_url }'
```

Give me this output

```
{
  "description": null,
  "rtmp_url": null
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Have you read the [mcve] guidelines?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming minor adjustments to your input to make it valid JSON,

```
jq -r '.features[].properties | "\(.description) \(.rtmp_url)"' input.json
```

produces

```
test description test url1
test 2 description test rtmp_url
```

as per the problem description.